# Linux:System calls for Who

Tags: linux

Working on making my own commands like linux pwd more who, kind of a stuck in who.
As I have read dirent and stat structures gives everything is there any struct which can give the functionality of who command.

Comment: Take a look yourself: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/who.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`who` is not implemented as a system call. It's just a human readable version of the file `/var/run/utmp`. Of course to read that file you do need system calls.

Just get the manual page for the `utmp` file

`$ man utmp`

And it will give you all the information you need to read that file and implement your own `who` command.